# GMSH 3D surface mesh

Tags: mesh, numeric, numerical-methods, finite-element-analysis

I've been trying without success to create a 3D SURFACE mesh using GMSH (v.3.0.6).

The problem that I am having is, after creating the surface and generating the mesh, when I read the .MSH file, I get a bizarre node numbering, i.e., not all the normal vectors are oriented outward, some points inward. I tried to create a cube and a sphere, but I always face the very same problem.

Below is the .GEO file I created using the GMSH GUI for the cube.

```
    // Gmsh project created on Fri Apr 20 17:08:44 2018
//+
Point(1) = {1, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(2) = {1, 1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(3) = {0, 1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(4) = {0, 0, 1, 1.0};
//+
Point(5) = {1, 0, 1, 1.0};
//+
Point(6) = {1, 1, 1, 1.0};
//+
Point(7) = {0, 1, 1, 1.0};
//+
Point(8) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Line(1) = {7, 6};
//+
Line(2) = {6, 5};
//+
Line(3) = {5, 1};
//+
Line(4) = {1, 8};
//+
Line(5) = {8, 3};
//+
Line(6) = {3, 7};
//+
Line(7) = {7, 4};
//+
Line(8) = {4, 8};
//+
Line(9) = {4, 5};
//+
Line(10) = {2, 1};
//+
Line(11) = {2, 6};
//+
Line(12) = {2, 3};
//+
Line Loop(1) = {6, 1, -11, 12};
//+
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
//+
Line Loop(2) = {11, 2, 3, -10};
//+
Plane Surface(2) = {2};
//+
Line Loop(3) = {2, -9, -7, 1};
//+
Plane Surface(3) = {3};
//+
Line Loop(4) = {6, 7, 8, 5};
//+
Plane Surface(4) = {4};
//+
Line Loop(5) = {8, -4, -3, -9};
//+
Plane Surface(5) = {5};
//+
Line Loop(6) = {10, 4, 5, -12};
//+
Plane Surface(6) = {6};
//+
Physical Surface(1) = {4, 3, 2, 6};
//+
Physical Surface(2) = {1};
//+
Physical Surface(3) = {5};
//+
Surface Loop(1) = {6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5};
//+
Volume(1) = {1};
```

Since I also define a volume, all the normal vectors are supposed to point OUTWARD. Any idea how can I make it right (or the way I need it to be)?

Thanks all in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of the lines in `Line Loop` affects what normal is going to be used in the `Surface` created from this `Line Loop`. You either have to be consistent in the ordering of the lines in ALL of your `Line Loops` – or you can flip the ordering for the ones causing troubles.

For the normals to point outwards, for this particular example, you can just change two lines:

```
Plane Surface(3) = {-3};
Plane Surface(4) = {-4};
```

That tells GMSH, to invert the ordering of the lines in the `Line Loop`, therefore obtaining the opposite normal.

For reference, here is the overall corrected GMSH script that generates the mesh with correct normals:

```
Point(1) = {1, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {1, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(3) = {0, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(4) = {0, 0, 1, 1.0};
Point(5) = {1, 0, 1, 1.0};
Point(6) = {1, 1, 1, 1.0};
Point(7) = {0, 1, 1, 1.0};
Point(8) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
Line(1) = {7, 6};
Line(2) = {6, 5};
Line(3) = {5, 1};
Line(4) = {1, 8};
Line(5) = {8, 3};
Line(6) = {3, 7};
Line(7) = {7, 4};
Line(8) = {4, 8};
Line(9) = {4, 5};
Line(10) = {2, 1};
Line(11) = {2, 6};
Line(12) = {2, 3};
Line Loop(1) = {6, 1, -11, 12};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
Line Loop(2) = {11, 2, 3, -10};
Plane Surface(2) = {2};
Line Loop(3) = {2, -9, -7, 1};
Plane Surface(3) = {-3};
Line Loop(4) = {6, 7, 8, 5};
Plane Surface(4) = {-4};
Line Loop(5) = {8, -4, -3, -9};
Plane Surface(5) = {5};
Line Loop(6) = {10, 4, 5, -12};
Plane Surface(6) = {6};
Physical Surface(1) = {4, 3, 2, 6};
Physical Surface(2) = {1};
Physical Surface(3) = {5};
Surface Loop(1) = {6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5};
Volume(1) = {1};
```

Comment: @Gabs what do you mean? That cannot be the case. Did you change your original lines to the ones with the minus signs keeping everything else the same?

Comment: Yes, I did. Gmsh creates a mesh only in four sides of the cube.

Comment: @Gabs I cannot see how it could be happening. I added the overall code to my answer – which is your with two fixed "-" signs and removed unnecessary comment lines.

Comment: Ok! Now it worked! Thanks! But how can I set it automatically? I mean, I must ensure that the normal vectors are all pointing outwards (and so, defining a volume).

Comment: @Gabs you cannot. You have to select/list lines in the same CCW order, but it is very hard to do. So you would usually examine the mesh for the normals and correct after.